# CakePHP - Auth hashed password different to Security::hash()

Tags: cakephp, passwords, authentication

On my password reset page, I save the user's new password using Security::hash().  When I then try to log in though, my database saved hashed password does not match the version that Auth comes up with when hashing my input in the login field.

I assume this is something like Security::hash() using my application salt to hash the password, whereas Auth doesn't use that salt?

How do you go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the [`AuthComponent::password()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-AuthComponent.html#_password) method instead?

Also, if the field is named `password`, check that AuthComponent hasn't already hashed it.

---

**Edit:** In 3.x, see [`DefaultPasswordHasher::hash()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Auth.DefaultPasswordHasher.html#_hash) instead, as explained in [Hashing Passwords](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords).

Comment: Thanks. That works but is it bad practice to be including components in models (where I am saving the new password)?  It seems like I could get Security to hash the password the same as Auth by specifying `Security::hash($password, 'sha1', Configure::read('Security.salt'))` but similarly that seems like it could be bad practice as it's not ensuring a consistency between which class is doing the password hashing across the entire application.

Comment: `AuthComponent` is already loaded and you can call the above method statically from your model. See this [old paste of mine](http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/35048) for usage example, though I would recommend the approach in [this blog post](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/10/08/demystifying-auth-features-in-cakephp-12/) over my `encryptPasswordField()` method.

Answer (score 1):

should be `Security::hash($password, 'sha1', true)`

you can leave the second parameter NULL because Auth use the same hash as specified in Security.